# VBA - macro msword - Insert table header after csv conversion

Tags: vba, row, ms-word

I'm working on an existing script macro in MSword 2007 (I didn't made it myself, don't blame me for a not so well done code design!).

This script takes SQL results from an ADODB connection and fill (delete and replace to be exact) a series of table at given bookmark, using the CSV conversion.

The task is to preserve the existent header and put all the results in the next rows dynamically. Catch is... the header can be made of merged cells

I'm not going to change a lot of code, and I'm no expert in VBA, but this is what I think should be the workflow:

- save the header (which is the "first" row of the base table)
- delete whole table
- insert CSV-converted table from the results
- insert header into the new generated table

Copying a row throw error when there are some merged cells. And it seems that VBA can only add empty rows... so probably I cannot "insert" the header as is. how can i put this header on the top of the table?

*help!!!*

```
Private Sub setRangeTable(bookmark As String, sqlCmd As String)
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim r As Range
    Dim t As table
    Dim c As Column
    Dim row As row
    Dim i As Integer
    'this variable should copy header
    Dim oldHeader As Range
    Set r = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(bookmark).Range
    With r.Tables(1)
        ' try to memorize the header (?)
        oldHeader = .Range(Start:=.Rows(1).Range.Start, _
            End:=.Rows(1).Range.End)
    End With
    r.Tables(1).Delete
    r.InsertAfter (getTableData(sqlCmd))
    r.Select
        r.ConvertToTable Separator:=wdSeparateByTabs, AutoFitBehavior:=wdAutoFitContent
        r.Tables(1).Rows(1).Select
        Selection.InsertRowsAbove
End Sub
```

example of existent table

```
----------------------
|      |      |     ....    | << cell of real row 1 \
| .... | .... |-------------|                       | << header
|      |      | .... | .... | << cell of real row 2 /
-----------------------------
|      |      |      |      | << all results...
-----------------------------
|      |      |      |      | << all results...
-----------------------------
|      |      |      |      | << all results...
-----------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a tricky situation. One problem with the code you provide is that you're deleting the table that contains the range with the header; assigning the table header to a variable won't protect it from deletion... Another factor is that you actually need rows 1 and 2, not just 1. And finally, Word won't let you address Rows(index) with merged cells.

The following works for me, in a quick test. The key is that it is possible to pick up the row(s) with the merged cells analogous to how the user can do it, using the keyboard.

Rather than delete the original table (corresponds to `tblOriginal` in my sample), first, the code works with a second table and only deletes the original one after the header has been copied over. Theoretically, you could use `Range.Cut` or `Range.Copy` and later `Range.Paste`, which would allow you to delete the original table earlier, but generally it's better not to use the Clipboard if another approach is possible.

This means you should insert one or two empty paragraph(s) after the first table, insert the csv there and convert it to a table, assigning it to a variable when you do (corresponds `tblTarget` in my code sample).

```
Dim tblOriginal As word.Table
Dim tblTarget As word.Table
Dim rngTblHeader As word.Range
Dim rngTarget As word.Range

Set tblOriginal = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
Set rngTblHeader = tblOriginal.Range
'Range at the beginning of first cell, then extend
rngTblHeader.Collapse wdCollapseStart
rngTblHeader.MoveEnd wdRow, 2
'rngTblHeader.Select 'debug/testing

Set tblTarget = ActiveDocument.Tables(2) 'You use r.ConvertToTable
Set rngTarget = tblTarget.Range
rngTarget.Collapse wdCollapseStart
rngTarget.FormattedText = rngTblHeader.FormattedText

tblOriginal.Delete
```

Comment: Magic code! Thank u a lot. Since you seem pretty good in vba, is there a method to know if there are merged cells in the first two rows? Sadly `setRangeTable()` is called blindly on tables which can have a 1-row header or 2-rows header. by the way if you don't have the time to answer no problem, this one is good enough for me. I'll go test.

Comment: @NereoCostacurta: You could check for .Cell(2,1) and trap error 5941, for example.

Comment: @NereoCostacurta This would merit a new Question, and please remember to describe the issue in detail, as well as including any code you've tried. I don't have anything I can "shake out of my sleeve" and it's been a while since I considered the problem...